# What are some applications of subdirect product?

Tags: group-theory, applications, direct-product

I have studied direct products. I know a few applications of direct products, like group isomorphism, *etc*. What are some applications of [sub-direct product](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subdirect_product) of groups?

Comment: Exercise: a group is isomorphic to a (nontrivial) subdirect product of two groups iff it has two nontrivial normal subgroups with trivial intersection. (By nontrivial subdirect, I mean none of the two projections is injective on the subgroup.)

Answer (score 2):

Subdirect products arise naturally as intransitive subgroups of $S_n$, where they are subdirect products of the induced actions of the group on its orbits. Similarly for completely reducible linear groups.

Comment: I was interested in the application in computer science.

Comment: Also, centralizers in the alternating group (e.g., of a 3-cycle) are usually naturally subdirect (fibre) products.

Answer (score 2):

A powerful tool in group theory is something called the fibre product. This is a special type of subdirect product of the group with itself.

> Associated to a short exact sequence $1\rightarrow N\rightarrow H\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 1$, where $\pi(H)=Q$ is the natural map, is the *fibre product* $P\subset H\times H$,
>   $$
> P:=\{(h_1, h_2)\mid \pi(h_1)=\pi(h_2)\}.
> $$

Clearly the diagonal component $\Delta:=\{(h, h)\mid h\in H\}$ is contained in $P$, so $P$ is a subdirect product.

The first application of fibre products which is know of is that there exist finitely generated subgroups of $F_2\times F_2$ which have insoluble membership problem: Firstly, let $Q$ be finitely presented and have insoluble word problem, then $P$ has insoluble membership problem. To see that $P$ is finitely generated, since $Q$ is ﬁnitely presented we have that $N \subset H$ is ﬁnitely generated *as a normal subgroup*, and then to obtain a ﬁnite generating set for $P$ one chooses a ﬁnite normal generating set for $N\times\{1\}$ and then appends a generating set for the diagonal $\Delta\cong H=F_2$.

A surprisingly powerful result, called the $1$-$2$-$3$ theorem, gives conditions on the fibre products to be finitely *presentable*, see:  G. Baumslag, M.R. Bridson, C.F. Miller III, H. Short, *Fibre products, non-positive curvature, and decision problems*, Comm. Math. Helv. **75** (2000), 457–477.

A super-powerful application of fibre products is the following (the application is the main result of a paper in the Annals of Mathematics, one of *the* top journals - undisputed top 4 journal, disputed no. 1). If $\Gamma$ is a group then $\widehat{\Gamma}$ denotes its profinite completion.

**Question** (Grothendieck, 1970). Let $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ be ﬁnitely presented, residually ﬁnite groups and let $u :\Gamma_1\rightarrow \Gamma_2$ be a homomorphism such that $\widehat{u} :\widehat{\Gamma}_1\rightarrow \widehat{\Gamma}_2$ is an isomorphism of proﬁnite groups. Does it follow that $u$ is an isomorphism from $\Gamma_1$ onto $\Gamma_2$?

**Theorem** (Bridson, Grunewald, 2004, Ann. Math., [link](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v160-n1-p08.pdf)). There exists a short exact sequence $1\rightarrow N\rightarrow\Gamma\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 1$ where $\Gamma$ has a whole host of nice properties, and where $P$ and $\Gamma$ are a counter-example to Grothendieck's question: $P$ and $\Gamma$ are finitely presentable, with $\widehat{P}\cong \widehat{\Gamma}$ but $P\not\cong \Gamma$.

Comment: @Shaun regarding your numerals edit, you might be interested in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38820/numbers-outside-math-environment) tex.SE question.

Comment: Thank you, @user1729; that'll save me some time in future! It's nice to know a useful convention :)

Comment: "A powerful tool in group theory, developed over the last 20 or so years but has a longer history". This sounds weird. I'd certainly not say that the tool of fibre products was developed in this period. Also if I prove a result about direct products I'm not developing the tool of direct product.

Comment: @YCor I'll remove the statement with the dates. However, I can only think of three results pre-Baumslag, Bridson, Miller, Short which use fibre products (but I think they invented the name?). So do you think it would be correct to say that they "came to the fore" in the past 20 years?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when you know that an object is a subdirect product of other objects, you know that it inherits all properties that are passed from products of those objects to their subsets. For example, a subdirect product of abelian groups must be abelian (and the same for any other group identity).

Comment: This seems to just be a property of a "subgroup of the direct product", which is a weaker property than being a subdirect product.